# How do i refresh or redraw table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

Below is the classical issue which I am facing during my app development. 
I have an array of JSONObjects in my spring controller that I have to iterate in the jsp; 
Also another status attribute called JSONArrayStatus is set that suggests if JSON array is empty or not.

Using jquery if JSONArray is empty I will show noDataImageDiv otherwise will show tableDIV (Binding the data from JSONArray using JSTL)

The problem I am facing is as below. 
1. Edit a row in the table and click on Update. At this time I make an Ajax Call say, "UpdatedUser", which will return all the records along with the updated records. I could use refresh however thats not a recommended user experience and hence a no no.

2. To reflect the updated users in the table, I use jquery as below

   - clearing table rows table.clear().draw()
   - Loop the result set as follows.

**redraw code**

```
function reDrawExternalContactUsers(externalUsers) {
    table.clear().draw();
    var row = "";
    $.each(externalUsers, function (i, field) {
        row = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td class="edit">edit</td></tr>';
        $("#tableDIV").append(row);
    });
}
```

afetr this redraw or refresh process

**This function is NOT working**

```
$(".edit").click(function(){ 
});
```

**This function is working**

```
$("#tableDIV .edit").click(function(){ 
});
```

Suggest a better way of refreshing table rows, if any.

```
<div id="tableDIV">
   <table id="tableID">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         if data exist
         loop{
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="edit">edit</td>
         </tr>
         } // loops ends
         if close
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<div id="noDataImageDiv"> No data image</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

html code :

```
<div id="tableDIV">
  <table id="tableID">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      if data exist
      loop{
      <tr>
        <td class="user-name"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="edit" data-user-id="">edit</td> //set user_id in attr data-user-id
      </tr>
      } // loops ends
      if close
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="noDataImageDiv"> No data image</div>
```

jquery code :

you should use click event on document

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
  var btn = $(this);
  var user_id = btn.attr("data-user-id"); //user_id of user will update
  // extra user data  
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
      'id': id,
      // extra data to send
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.status) // successfully user updated
      {
        var user = data.user;
        /* you can set user data like this */
        btn.closest('tr').find('.user-name').html(user.name);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the other best way

Comment: what if i want to use loop   $('#ContactsParentDIV .selectUser:checked').each(function(){

Comment: in which term you are using loop? for get all checked user ?

Comment: In other way get only updated user details in ajax sucess callback and set it to user details.